# friend suggestion in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, neo4jphp

I am trying to get friend suggestions to work within my app and its been an exciting yet frustrating time learning Neo4J comming from a RDBMS background but here I go.

I need to be able to show people that know two or more direct friends of a user. In other words as per the graph in the attached screen shot I need a Cypher Query which gives me nodes 6 and 4.

A screenshot can be found on http://oi39.tinypic.com/j9yogi.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated with this cause I am ripping my hair out.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You show the graphic, but have you tried any cypher out so far?

Answer (score 3):

As Nicholas pointed out, if you try some Cypher, it's pretty easy.

See http://console.neo4j.org/r/kt5hd

```
START n=node(1) 
MATCH n-[r:KNOWS*2]->f 
WITH count(r) AS count, f 
WHERE count>=2 
RETURN f
```

Comment: My graph has been updated and now contains bidirectional relationships. eg: 1 knows 2 and 2 knows 1 . How would I update this query to cater for this situation. I have tried MATCH n<-[r:KNOWS*2]->f but that doesnt seem to work. Your help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Remove the directions completely i.e. MATCH n-[r:KNOWS*2]-f

Comment: Hi Luanne, That still returns 0 rows :(

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with Gremlin. You have the example in the doc: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/gremlin-plugin.html#rest-api-collaborative-filtering

Answer (score 0):

@Luannes answer will also return current friends as well which is not really friend suggestion. Use this.

```
            MATCH (joe { name: 'Joe' })-[:knows*2..2]-(friend_of_friend)
            WHERE NOT (joe)-[:knows]-(friend_of_friend)
            RETURN friend_of_friend.name, COUNT(*)
            ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC , friend_of_friend.name
```

From the Neo4j cookbook
http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-cookbook-friend-finding.html